# add more elements in listview row like textbox and button IN C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

how can i add more than element in listview row design like add binding and button ? in same gridview column in c# WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a Panel derivative (such as StackPanel or Grid) inside the column's template, then add multiple controls to the panel.